# How to scale a barplot in ggplot2 with two variables when one variable is of the order of 1000 times smaller than the other?

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, bar-chart

I am comparing the execution times of binary search and linear search and displaying them using a bar plot.

But since the execution times of binary search are almost 1000 times less than linear search, the bars for binary search are barely visible.

Is there a way to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are looking for `+ scale_y_log10()`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using micobenchmark? It’s really concise

https://www.r-bloggers.com/2015/01/using-the-microbenchmark-package-to-compare-the-execution-time-of-r-expressions/